# Maya:change parent of object at the time of Animation

Tags: python, maya, mel

i want change parent of object in the frame for example i have 3 object in my maya project i want third object child first object in frame 0 to 10 then in frame 10 change Third object parent to second object.

can i do it white maya?or need write script python/mel?

how do it?

Comment: https://forums.creativecow.net/archivethread/61/70091

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To do this you'd need a parent constraint instead of a regular parenting relationship:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GkDNwFZgc-Y

You'll need to animate the weight values so that the constraint follows one object exclusively at a time.